# Material design - icon size in navigation drawer

Tags: android, material-design

I was wondering, in material design, what should be the icon size for navigation drawer.

I had gone through https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html# , but they didn't mentioned on icon size.

Some had mentioned the size should be 24dp - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118325/what-sizes-should-an-image-in-an-navigation-drawer-be, but doesn't provide reference source to support his answer.

I had created both 32dp & 24dp version (Please to left side icon. I didn't did any change on right side icon)

### 32dp

[image]

### 24dp

[image]

I was wondering, which is the correct spec?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is mentioned in the **Metrics and Key-lines** Documentation page on Material Design Guidelines.

*The Icons need to be smaller than the Avatar.*

Avatar needs to be 40DP along with an additional 8DP of touch target area.

Similarly, the **icon needs to be 24x24**, with an additional 24dp of touch target area.

[image]

See it here:
http://www.google.com.br/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-touch-target-size

So yes, **24DP** however, with a 48dp total touch target area.

Use the [Keyline Pushing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.faizmalkani.keylines&hl=en) app to test if you're following the correct metrics.